# Can a noun be qualified by two juxtaposed adjectives?

Tags: grammar-identification, adjective, conjunction

I read online (I'm sorry, I can't remember where) that if two adjectives refer to the same noun, you have to use a conjunction like "et" or "-que".

> Socrates sapiens senex vir est. (incorrect)

> Socrates sapiens senexque vir est. (correct)

Is this true? If so, is it only classical or in all Latin styles?

I remember reading "integrum inlaesum" in a letter by Pline.

Comment: ? *Sapiens senex vir* is acceptable on the verge if *senex vir* is taken as a whole. Since *senex* may be substantivized, *sapiens senex* would be said instead, the AP being directly dominated by DP (instead of implying a silent N head <vir>). Note that here, the two As would not be juxtaposed, but embedded; so this does not contradict the rule.

Answer (score 6):

The rule you read is essentially correct, but:

1. It applies only to *pairs* of words, not to longer lists. If three or more elements are combined, the asyndeton (no conjunctions) is used, or conjunctions are used with every member, or the last member has a *-que*. Your example from Pliny is an example of the latter: *corpus inventum integrum inlaesum opertumque* ([Plin. ep. 6, 16](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/pliny.ep6.html)) <sup>1)</sup>
2. There are some exceptions: If an adjective modifies a noun to express not just a property of the thing, but essentially a particular type of thing, and then that expression is modified by another adjective, there is no *et*. An obvious example: *navis longa* is usually not a ship that happens to be long, it's a warship; so we say: *navis longa vetus* (an old warship). But also for example *columna aurea solida*. It's like in English you don't wish somebody “a happy and new year.” Note that while numerals are formally adjectives, they are not combined with *et*, e.g. *tres fortes viri*, but very frequently you see e.g. *multi et fortes viri*. There are also some fixed expressions like *Iuppiter optimus maximus*.

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is a very famous letter by the way: [Pliny the Younger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliny_the_Younger) writing to [Tacitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacitus), describing the death of his uncle, [Pliny the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliny_the_Elder), during the [volcanic eruption that destroyed Pompeii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruption_of_Mount_Vesuvius_in_79_AD).

Comment: Excellent answer. This is really as in French, *un gros et hideux bonhomme* vs *un gros hideux bonhomme*. You can say *pulchra navis longa* because *navis longa* is taken as a whole, *longa* being determinative and thus, located after the N. But aside from such cases, you need to coordinate the last two terms. In English, I believe it is somehow easier to say *a fat ugly man*.

Comment: @VincentKrebs That's strange to my ears. I would always say 'an ugly fat man', and there's a "rule" for it, too: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/sep/13/sentence-order-adjectives-rule-elements-of-eloquence-dictionary

Comment: @cmw Ok well, I'm not native but anyway, substantially it doesn't change anything, i.e. juxtaposition and embedding should not be mixed up.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Oh, I was only commenting on just that last sentence, not anything before it.

Comment: @cmw Sure :) Thanks for the link.