# et indicating two separate adjectives or one adjective qualifying another

Tags: conjunctive

In the following sentence the Loeb translated it into English as shown:

*His diebus locis temperatis **et** maritimis messis conficitur...* ("During these days the harvest finishes in temperate places near the sea...")

Just looking at it naively I would have translated it as "During these days the harvest finishes in temperate and maritime places..." which is obviously a different meaning. Which is correct and why?

Assuming the translators version is correct, then how would you write the way I translated it any different? Would it have to read *His diebus locis **et** temperatis **et** maritimis messis conficitur...* in order to have that meaning?

Comment: Just as a quick note, it's not that *et* means "near", it's that *temperatis* and *maritimis* both modify *locis*. It's *maritimis* that means "near the sea."

Comment: @cmw If that were the case, then it could just read "locis temperatis maritimis" which means "temperate places near the sea". There would be no need for "et" at all. I guess I am completely confused whether it is talking about temperate and maritime places separately or whether maritime is qualifying the temperate places (which is how the Loeb translator has it).

Comment: @cmw I have changed the title of the question to make the question more clear

Comment: It's possible, but it would be a stylistic choice. Latin more commonly adds a conjunction between two adjectives that describe the same noun (as does English). Do note though that "near the sea" in English is a prepositional phrase, and so is grammatically different from *maritimus*, which is an we just don't have a great word that corresponds with *maritimus* directly (except, of course, for "maritime", which we borrowed from Latin).

Comment: I thought the question was clear! I just wanted to add that little note about the meaning of *et*.

Comment: The quotation is from Columella, *De re rustica* 11.2.54. Please cite sources.

Answer (score 3):

Two adjectives modifying the same noun *must* usually be joined by *et*, *atque* or enclitic *-que*. (Quo longius huic situi intersum, eo frequentius mihi licet dicere: Vide et [priorem responsum meum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19429/can-a-noun-be-qualified-by-two-juxtaposed-adjectives/19431#19431).) Leaving out the conjunction is usually not correct.

If Columella had written *locis temperatis maritimis*, then I would assume that *loci maritimi* form a category to him, and he qualifies them as temperate. The other way around, although suggested by the word order, seems far-fetched to me. But as he wrote it, being temperate and being near the sea appear to be attributes on equal footing to him, presumably both describing the climate in some way.

Now, I might be wrong, but I haven't read anything in a Latin grammar that would explicitly rule out the interpretation that he is referring to places that are temperate *or* near the sea, but if you want to express that explicitly, you could probably write *locis temperatis aut maritimis*.